# Export Result of query to file SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a complex query, when I execute it, I get a big table so I would like to export it to a file, instead of inserting it to a table.

for example, lets say we have a query:

```
select
  (select Name from Table1 where ID = 1),
  (select Name from Table2 where ID = 25),
   ...
```

How would I export result to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this directly in SSMS? There is a button in the toolbar labeled **Results To File** which does exactly what you want. Or you can use [openrowset](http://thiagsundar.wordpress.com/export-data-to-text-file/)

Comment: @darkcminor Ooops, sorry, forgot to add the link. I changed that.

Comment: Also, if there are other queries above the one that I want in a file?